# How to prove or disprove transitivity of relation

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

I have a relation $R$ on a set $G$ defined as $(a,b) \in R$ if $ab = ba$. It is pretty clear that this is reflexive and symmetric, but how do I prove or disprove transitivity?

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, I forgot to specify that $G$ is a group.

Comment: Is $G$ actually a group? If so, please say so in your question.

Comment: @AlexG. Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more explicit than the other answers, take the group $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices. Let $a = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right), b = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right),$ and $c = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$. Then $ab = ba = a$ and $bc = cb = c$, but $ac \neq ca$. Thus, this relation is not transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
transitivity means that
$aRb \land bRc
\implies aRc$.

In this case,
$aRb$ means
$ab = ba$.
$bRc$ means
$bc = cb$.

So,
does
$(ab = ba)
\land (bc = cb)
\implies ac = ca$?

Comment: That's my question...

Answer (score 0):

To show transitivity you need to show that if $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ then $(a,c) \in R$.

However, depending on the set G, this condition may or may not be satisfied.

For example:

If $G = \mathbb{R}$ then the relation is transitive since $\mathbb{R}$ is abelian. If G is the set of 2x2 matrices then it is not transitive.